# Auto Blacklist Bot IPs using GET requests in NGINX

Tags: http, nginx, bots, ddos

I am fairly new to NGINX, so sorry if this question appears stupid, but here is my case.

I am experiencing a DDoS layer 7 get attack. I want to blacklist all the IPs that are making GET request. For 24 hours there are more than 1 000 000 unique IPs that are entering my website (according to my access log), which will make it impossible to go and deny them one by one.

So far I tried Limiting the Rate of Requests, Limiting the Number of Connections, Closing Slow Connections, but sadly this is not helping me. Nginx is still giving 500 error, and from time to time error 503 service unavailable.

So, my goal is to deny all the IPs that are making a GET request, but it has to be an automatic process, because otherwise it would be an impossible job.

Comment: If you blacklist all IPs that send GET-requests. What requests you will pass?

Comment: I want to pass only the IPs that browse the website. The bots are exploiting my search form. If I remove it, the real users are not going to make searches, so everything else will be bots, that I want to ban. 

Accept for the searches the bots are trying to get images with random names. I would try to think of a way to block them as well.

Comment: What do you mean:  "browse the website"? When any user from web browser try to open your site, he also send GET-request. So if you block all GET-requests, you will also block all human requests.

Comment: Yes you are right, so my goal is to block every IP that goes to "/search?query=" because, this is the only marker I can find the bots are sharing in common.

Comment: Are you sure, that humans can't send requests to "/search?query="? Because if you block all requests to this URI, humans also couldn't send request to this URI...

Comment: Yes, I will disable the form, so it can't be reached by the humans. (At least most of them)

Comment: If you disable the form, "/search" URI still be available for GET-requests?

Comment: Yes, it will be, and my goal is everyone, who makes a search will be banned form the website, because 99.99% of the searches will be made by bots.

Comment: I've tried to deny access to location /search but after that, the bots start to search for random images, and still manage to kill NGINX, if I block them in total, I think I can save the website.

Comment: "bots start to search for random images, and still manage to kill NGINX" In this case bots received 404 code?

Comment: Yes, they do, and I don't know why, for some reason, I still get error 500 by nginx. My server CPU is getting to its normal rate, but NGINX crashes. If it is not restricted, php-fpm takes 100% of the CPU.

Comment: Please provide your nginx vhost configuration. Only locations will be enough...

Comment: location / 
{
 limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 10;
 limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=5 nodelay;
}

location /search
{
 deny all;
}

Comment: It is all configuration of your "location /"? No one "proxy_pass" or "fastcgi_pass"?

Comment: location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|html|ico|woff|ttf|ott|eot)$ {
 error_page 404 = /index.php?$query_string;
 expires 31536000s;
 add_header Pragma public;
 add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }

location ~ \.php$ {


        if (!-f $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
      return 404;
  }

 add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

 #FastCGI options
}

Comment: This is all, no proxy_pass. Will this help with the flood?

Comment: Probably is going to be faster en safe to enable http://cloudflare.com/ on your site than blocking all GET requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue happens because of string:

```
error_page 404 = /index.php?$query_string;
```

This string means, that if you return 404, execute php-code. Try to comment this string.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue indeed. Now the bots are blocked and the website is flying. The only problem now is with the search form. How to filter the bots and let only humans make searches? Should I set captcha for verification?

Comment: I will! Tank you very much for the help!